# Xamarin and httpclient requests returns ok within emulator but nothing on device

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2019, dotnet-httpclient

Trying to get my Xamarin-app to go to an url and fetch the response (which is just a string). When I try it in the Visual Studio Emulator it works ok, and the Content contains the expected string, but when debugging or deploying to my testphone (Samsung S8 - Android v9.0) the response code is still ok, but the Content is empty.

When using an url with https it seems to work ok most of the time, but when trying to use my test-url which is not https, the above scenario happens.

Is HttpClient not working without https on Android-devices?
Are there any settings I need to set within my project to allow non-https-calls?

Comment: See my Xamarin.Android answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55997456/4984832

Comment: Sorry, didn't help adding the NetworkSecurity-settings. Same behaviour as earlier. In emulator it returns text ok, but on device "" (empty string..) but thank you for the response.

Comment: "cleartextTrafficPermitted" ?